# Polymer 2.0 : Super keyword in custom element callbacks

Tags: ecmascript-6, polymer, super, polymer-2.x

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements

> For each reaction, the first line of your implementation must be a
>   call to the superclass constructor or reaction. For the constructor,
>   this is simply the super() call.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  // …
}
```

what is the use of super() here.

Comment: The quote you posted answers this. `a call to the superclass constructor`

Comment: actually my question what does it actually do, under the hood.